# Android software update

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, internal-storage

I am with Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini Android 4.2.2 JB which has to be upgradable up to 4.4.3 KK.
However the software actualization keep fails due to a lack of free memory in the phone and SD card.

It shouldn't fail since I have 1GB of free space on the phone (actualization is /500mb/) and 14 GB of free space on the SD card.

What am I supposed to do to solve this?

Comment: You can try to move some apps to your SD card because there may be to little space on your phone. I recommend DU Speed Booster because it has a move to SD feature which tells you which apps can be moved... Hope it helps

Comment: I already have DU Speed Booster apps. I removed all the movable apps.

Comment: If you can, backup your data and Factory Reset your device, setup the initial phase then go straight to the upgrade. This should allow your phone to update before you install any third party apps etc. Not the continent way but it should work.

Comment: I would say the reason why its showing error is because of the space, maybe you should consider moving some of the bulky apps over to the SD card, or I would also say that its better to Head over to the Settings>application manager> Swipe left to all and start uninstalling the application that you don’t use much as the update you are going to put over your device may look for more of the device internal storage.  And still if that doesn’t helps then better will be installing some cleaner apps like CCleaner apps over the device as sometimes it does helps in clearing junk space occupied.......

Comment: You can uninstall all updates to stock apps such a google play store because the update are going to be installed anyway during the android update...

Comment: Yes thanks. I think backup of everything should fix the problem.

Comment: Try Settings => Apps => All => delete cache